# How to store a radio button in a session for use on another page?

Tags: php, html, session, post

So I need to store the choice of selected radio button in session and then based on that value perform an action on a different page.

Page1.php:

```
 <input type="radio" name="person" value="p1"/>Person1
 <input type="radio" name="person" value="p2"/>Person2
```

Page2.php

```
if Person1 is selected on page one
  //do this
if Person2 is selected one page two
  //do this
```

Comment: You need to post them in form to second page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by posting the data in your form through to your Page2.php page you don't need a session.

```
$_POST["person"];
```

Will pull the data out so that you can do:

```
string person = $_POST["person"]
if(person == something){
   //do something
}
else{
  //do something else
}
```

You only need a session if you intend to use the variable value that is returned on multiple occasions. If that's the case then you can find a good easy tutorial here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

The basics would look something like this within your Page2.php:

```
session_start();    
$_SESSION["person"] = $_POST["person"];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to start a session in Page2.php

start by calling (at the top of your page)

```
 <?php
   session_start();

   //post your data
   $person = $_POST['person'];



   $_SESSION['person'] = $person;
 ?>
```

You will have to have the inputs be wrapped inside of a form:

```
 <form method="post" action="Page2.php">
   <input type="radio" name="person" value="p1"/>Person1
   <input type="radio" name="person" value="p2"/>Person2      
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

 </form>
```

Now you will be able to use that $_SESSION variable on mostly any page, if the session is not destroyed or overwritten.

To retrieve a session value on another page, simply use:

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   $person = $_SESSION['person'];

 ?>
```