# How to determine which radio button is selected in second page using session

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two radio buttons and the session to store which button is selected, which I want to access in my second page.

On selection of each radio button, there will be different fields to be displayed in second page which is modal.

For example, if user selects first one (e.g.: date and time filled should be hidden) on second it should display. How to do this?

Comment: After submit on first page move to PHP page, get state of first radio button, save it to the session, then on next page get the data and show fields accordingly

Comment: show some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009488/how-to-store-a-radio-button-in-a-session-for-use-on-another-page This should help you out.

Comment: In the first page i have radio buttons like this
<label>
              <input type="radio" name="radio" value="one way" id="id_radio" onclick="hide();" />One Way</label>
               <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radio" value="round trip" id="id_radio3" onclick="show();" />Round Trip</label>
And session , to store this and check which one is selected

Comment: <?php                                                                            
        session_start();
        if (isset($_POST['radio'])){
       $_SESSION['r1']=$_POST['radio'];
      }
      $one = '';
      $round = '';
      if($_SESSION['r1']=="one way"){
        $one = "checked";
      }else if($_SESSION['r1']=="round trip"){
         $round = "checked";
      }
     ?>
In second page i have modal which contains  different fields for different radio button, on clicking it should identify which button is selected and it should hide the other fields  another radio button

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
 <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="reason" value="1">Executed</label>
</td>
<td>
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="reason" value="2">Expired</label>
 </td>
<td>    
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="reason" value="3">Another Option</label>
 </td>
```

and PHP code

```
//$reason = $_REQUEST['reason']; OR
$reason=$_POST['reason'];
```

Comment: OP has not presented a well structured question here, and it is diffcult to assume. plus OP wants to do this with session variables

Answer (score 0):

this is your form data and you can change action if you want . suppose first submit form in same page2 then use this code

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
       <input type="radio" name="reason" value="1"/>Reason1
       <input type="radio" name="reason" value="2"/>Reason2
       <input type="radio" name="reason" value="3"/>Reason3     
       <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

     </form>
```

in second page this is code

and you want to use this value any place then use this code in your any place from project

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $reason = $_SESSION['reason'];
   echo $reason;
 ?>
```